# jCalendar display trash in background

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

I have a JCalendar in a JPanel and a JList in another JPanel, but something happen in the month combobox, when I click in a JList item the background display a part of the JList item, like this:

[image: jcalendar]

I'm on a Mac, I don't know if this is a nimbus look and a feel bug, or something. But a friend with Windows have the same issue. I'm using JCalendar v.1.4

Comment: Please consider add a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) recreating the problem to your question. Based on your post we can only make guesses.

Comment: I think it's a problem executing the project in netbeans, because when I open the .jar file, it work without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are both, the JCalendar and the JList's Panel, in a same Higher JPanel (which works as a container) ?
If you are in this situation, a solution will be to Revalidate the Container after displaying the current visible JPanel.

See It like this:

First:

```
  A JCalendar in a first JPanel : JPanelCalendar
  A JList in a second JPanel    : JPanelList
  Both in a JPanel              : JPanelConatainer
```

You must do:

```
  JPanelContainer.revalidate();
```

Secondly:

Be sure that you do a,

```
    JPanelCalendar.setVisible(false);
```

When you want to show JPanelList and vice versa.

Third:

Perhaps your issue is because JPanelCalendar is not Opaque, to correctly hide the seconde one,

```
    JPanelCalendar.setOpaque(true);
```

But after all, don't forget to hide one of them before diplaying the other one. 
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: i have 2 big panels, jPanelLeft, jPanelRight, 
jPanelLeft: jCalendar and another stuff
jPanelRight: Jlist and another jpanel, but i dont have contained for both panels. and it happens when i pass the mouse over the month combobox

Comment: Can you paste a code about what you really do in code behind, when you click on the JList Item ?

Answer (score 0):

I just have a same bug.

It is happens only with **Nimbus L&F**, and only with **JMountChooser**.

> Decision is really easy: right button on JMountChooser -> Properties
>   -> remove option "Opaque".

Just tested - works fine!